# Pinescript not displaying info about my plot in alert message

Tags: pine-script

I am using placeholder and also tried with tostring but it is not displaying the info in the alert message, What am I missing?

It's only displaying as is..

```
entry_long_message = 'key = XXX
     pair=adausdt /n
     //stoplossPercentage=tostring(stopperclong) /n
     stoplosspercentage =  {{plotchar("stop_long")}} + "/n"
     exchange=binance /n
     type=entry /n
     leverage=tostring(leveragelong) /n
     exchangeAccountType=futures /n
     side=long /n
     positionSizePercentage=tostring(posperclong) /n
     orderType=market /n
     signalId = adalongfutures '
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Combining strings with TradingView's addition operator](https://kodify.net/tradingview/operators/combine-strings-addition/)

You need to concatenate every variable you have with `+` to the strings with fixed text.
Also, a carriage return is `\n` instead of `/n`.

Example

```
var int myValue = 20
var string myText = na
myText := "Fixed text " + tostring(myValue) + " more fixed text \n" + "this will be on another line " + tostring(myValue)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel that it solved your problem, please accept the answer so that others can benefit from it too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as you expect.

`message` argument of the `alertcondition` function accept a *constant string*, `plot`'s values and some *built-in* variables, such as `close`, `volume` inside a *placeholder*. See more info here: https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/introducing-variables-in-alerts-14880/

To be able to pass a dynamic string to the message argument you have to plot the value and then link that plot to the placeholder. You can hide that plot with the `display` argument if you do not wish to see it on your charts.

Ex:

```
plot(someVariable, "someVariablePlotName", display = display.none)

alertcondition(someCondition, "alertName", message = 'constant string plus dynamic value from the plot function: {{plot("someVariablePlotName")}}, current price : {{close}}')
```

So you have to create a separate plot for each of your dynamic variables (stopperclong, leveragelong, posperclong etc) and include that plot in the message argument with a placeholder.